# ajax loading of data in slick grid

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I've been trying to modify an example of slickgrid on github-
[AJAX loading](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/blob/gh-pages/examples/example6-ajax-loading.html) to load data from MySQL via php page asyncronously.

Unfortunately, the example's URL no longer works.
And I'm having trouble with PHP file that would serve the data.

Does anyone have a working example of async data load from MySQL into slickGrid?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you know how to build a basic REST call in PHP?